# Show message when txt file is empty

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can't get this to work, what am I doing wrong?
I tried to remove the PHP but that didn't trigger the JS either.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flahultsskolan Fr&aring;nvarande Ram</title>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function isEmpty(){
                 if( $('#content').is(':empty') ) {
                    $('.content').prepend("Hej");
                 }
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family:helvetica;font-size:14px;height:auto;">
        <div id="content" class="content" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
            <?php include("edit/franvarande.txt"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So... what does it do, and what is it meant to do?

Comment: This file a `.php` extension? *I had to ask.*

Comment: Why are you trying to include a text file? include() expects a PHP file, try http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @Jackhardcastle You can include (almost) any file type, just as long as the server supports it. 9 times out of 10, they do. I can include .txt .shtml etc. I do it all the time.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, my bad, however anything called by the include function still gets parsed by the PHP interpreter, so it's best to avoid that unnecessary processing.

Comment: `content` isn't empty its contains `waitspace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is whitespace in your div, which also exists when the text file is empty. Instead, do:

```
<div id="content" class="content" style="margin:0;padding:0;"><?php include("edit/franvarande.txt"); ?></div>
```

However, `include()` is *meant* for PHP files. If your file is 'just text', you could use `file_get_contents()`, so that the file doesn't go through PHP, instead:

```
<div id="content" class="content" style="margin:0;padding:0;"><?php echo file_get_contents("edit/franvarande.txt"); ?></div>
```

You can split it up over three lines for readability:

```
<div id="content" class="content" style="margin:0;padding:0;"><?php 
    echo file_get_contents("edit/franvarande.txt"); 
?></div>
```

Have a look at this snippet. The top right table cell is 'empty', but has whitespace, and because of this it's not selected with `:empty`.

```
$( "td:empty" )
  .text( "Was empty!" )
  .css( "background", "rgb(255,220,200)" );


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr><td>TD #0</td><td>  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>TD #2</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td>TD#5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works like a charm! I use the php include tag on more places to include a txt file, should I change them too?

Comment: *"However, include() is meant for PHP files (it will probably work, but the file will pass through the PHP parser, which is unnecessary)"* - I beg to differ and where does this say in the manual about using `.php` exclusively? Read the manual yourself http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php - There's a misconception on your part in regards to your comment. Look at Example #3 include through HTTP on that page, and look at all the `// Works`. I use `include()` for a lot of different file extensions.

Comment: @Fred the manual continously talks about the code that is being included, hence my idea that it is primarily meant for PHP. I don't see exactly what ex. 3 has to do with it. But yes, things like this do work, most of the time if not always.

Comment: It has everything to do with it. The OP can use `.txt` `.html` etc. I use it all the time. Sorry, but I don't agree fully with that statement.

Comment: @Fred what do you make of the manual talking about the _code_ being included?

Comment: I can run instructions/PHP directives taken from a `.txt` file. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: @Fred yes, you can. What I'm saying is that `include` is meant for those cases where there is something to execute. Otherwise, `file_get_contents` would be better. But you can indeed include a TXT.

Comment: Yes, that ^ I completely agree with.

Answer (score 1):

This would be simpler like this:

```
$('#content:empty').text('Hej');
```

There is no need for another test, `#content:empty` supplies the test.

However, the initial problem is that the div block contains whitespace and should be done inside one single line.

```
<div id="content" class="content" style="margin:0;padding:0;"><?php include("edit/franvarande.txt"); ?></div>
```

Doing this will **not** work, in case you wanted to try that later on:

```
<div id="content" class="content" style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<?php include("edit/franvarande.txt"); ?>
</div>
```

- (Hidden) Carriage returns count as data and will be considered as *not empty*, in turn failing.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. This will not solve his problem: his code should work fine (even though it could be smaller).

Comment: As Camil said, that doesn't work either. But thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: It's the whitespace @9focuspoints. I'll have an update shortly.

Comment: Together with Camils comments this is clearly the best looking solution!

Comment: @CamilStaps *"This will not solve his problem: his code should work fine (even though it could be smaller)."* - This tells me "his code should work fine **just the way it is**". That should have been phrased as "his code should work the way I have outlined in my answer, because of the whitespace which is in OP's code". Let's dot the i's and cross the t's here.

Comment: Indeed. What I meant was that **that** part of the code, which is improved here, should work fine. OP's code and the improvement are functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Also if `php` include return an empty string `` with your code structure the `.content` isn't `:empty`.

It has some whitespace inside.

To prevent this problem you can edit your include @Keelan suggests or you an use a script like this:

```
if($('#content').text().trim().length < 1) {
    $('#content').prepend("Hej");
}
```

`.trim()` cleans by whitespace the string returned from `.text()`.